# Jest - Mock a constant property from a module for a specific test

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, commonjs

So, I'm attempting to do something which on the surface should be very simple...

I have some constants defined in:

```js
//constants.js

module.exports = {
 MY_CONSTANT: "TEST"
}
```

I have a file which I'm trying to test which has a branching statement like this:

```js
//file to test
//...
    
if(CONSTANTS.MY_CONSTANT === "TEST")
{...}
...
```

And I have a test like this:

```js
//test
it("Should do something when MY_CONSTANT === "TEST, () => {
  //This is fine as it is exported as TEST
})
   
it("Should do something else when MY_CONSTANT !== "TEST, () => {
  //This seems annoyingly difficult to get working...
})
```

[I've tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977961/how-to-mock-an-exported-const-in-jest) - With no luck, it doesn't change the actual value

I've tried changing the constant export to export an object instead (that didn't work)

I've tried adding a `jest.mock(...)` for the constants in my test file and doing an unmock in the tests I don't need them mocked.

I've tried adding a `jest.doMock(...)` within the test function I need to change the value. (along with `jest.resetModules` and another require)

I've tried adding a `jest.doMock(...)` to a tests beforeEach (along with `jest.resetModules` and another require)

I'm at a loss really...literally all I want to do is change a property value before a test runs

**Update**
So I've done some of the suggestions made:

I now have a **mocks** folder adjacent to the constant folder
It contains a file named the same as the actual constants file and a custom export

I've then added `jest.mock("../constants);` inside the test.

I've then also added a `const funcImTesting = require("../../file").testFunction` inside the test.

Still the constant remains unchanged and the test fails.

Answer (score 22):

File that exports a constant value that I want to mock:

```
// utils/deviceTypeUtils file
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

export const isTablet = DeviceInfo.isTablet();
```

In my test file, I use this code to mock the constant `isTablet`:

```
// file: deviceTypeUtils.spec
const DeviceTypeUtilsMock = jest.requireMock('../utils/deviceTypeUtils');
jest.mock('../utils/deviceTypeUtils', () => ({
  isTablet: false,
}));

describe('mock const example', () => {
  it('mock const `isTablet` to the value `true`', () => {
    DeviceTypeUtilsMock.isTablet = true;
  });

  it('mock const `isTablet` to the value `false`', () => {
    DeviceTypeUtilsMock.isTablet = false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the need to revert the mock to `true` at the end of the "mock const isTable to the value true" test? So that all following tests use the default mock value (`false`), and don't have to explicitely set this value to `false` themselves?

Answer (score 8):

To mock for one test only:

```js
jest.mock('./constants.js', () => ({
  MY_CONSTANT: 'something fake'
}));
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks

---

To provide a mock for every test:

1. create a `__mocks__` directory **adiacent** to the module you desire to mock
2. provide implementation
3. call `jest.mock('./moduleName')` in your test

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules

Comment: So that's true, I can do that. However, since there are 2 tests and each testing a different value of the constant...there's no way I can see to mock it for 1 single test.So it's not really a solution that works here

Comment: I've tried adding a mock module to a__mocks__ directory, jest.mock seems to do absolutely nothing when inside a test

Comment: you may require dependant files afterwards... or please, update your question with the given scenario.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect current scenario

Answer (score 8):

I have been able to do something similar by following the post at https://mikeborozdin.com/post/changing-jest-mocks-between-tests/

This creates a mock and then changes it for each test.

```
import * as constants from './constants'

jest.mock('./constants', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  MY_CONSTANT: 'SOME OTHER DEFAULT',
}))

it("Should do something when MY_CONSTANT === "TEST, () => {
  constants.MY_CONSTANT = 'TEST'
  expect(constants.MY_CONSTANT).toBe('TEST')
})

it("Should do something else when MY_CONSTANT !== "TEST, () => {
  constants.MY_CONSTANT = 'NOT A TEST'
  expect(constants.MY_CONSTANT).toBe('NOT A TEST')
})
```

If you are using typescript then the mock needs to be cast to modify the mock values:

```
const mockConstants = constants as { MY_CONSTANT: string }
mockConstants.MY_CONSTANT = 'TEST'
```

Answer (score 5):

Follow the guidance of the [doc on `jest.doMock()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options)

The `config.js` file:

```
export const env = 'test';
```

The `myComponent.js` file:

```
import {env} from './config.js';

export const MyComponent = () => {
  if (env === 'prod') {
    return (<Text>Prod Env</Text>);
  } else if (env === 'test'){
    return (<Text>Test Env</Text>);
  } else {
    return (<Text>Dev Env</Text>);
  }
};
```

The `myComponent.test.js` file:

```
describe('Test MyComponent', () => {
  test('Test in prod env', () => {
    jest.doMock('./config', () => ({env: 'prod'}));
    const {MyComponent} = require('./myComponent.js');
    const myComp = mount(<MyComponent />);
    expect(myComp.find('Text')).toHaveText('Prod Env');
  });

  test('Test in test env', () => {
    jest.doMock('./config', () => ({env: 'test'}));
    const {MyComponent} = require('./myComponent.js');
    const myComp = mount(<MyComponent />);
    expect(myComp.find('Text')).toHaveText('Test Env');
  });

  test('Test in dev env', () => {
    jest.doMock('./config', () => ({env: 'dev'}));
    const {MyComponent} = require('./myComponent.js');
    const myComp = mount(<MyComponent />);
    expect(myComp.find('Text')).toHaveText('Dev Env');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just copy constants and assign them after each test case.

```
const constants = require('./constants');
const original = {...constants};
afterEach(() => {
    Object.assign(constants, original);
});
test('test1', () => {
    constants.ABC = 'whatever';
});
test('test2', () => {
    // constants.ABC is set back to original
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by initializing constants from ContstantsFile.js in reducers. And placed it in redux store. As jest.mock was not able to mock the contstantsFile.js

```
constantsFile.js
-----------------
const MY_CONSTANTS = {
MY_CONSTANT1: "TEST",
MY_CONSTANT2: "BEST",
};
export defualt MY_CONSTANTS;

reducers/index.js
-----------------
import MY_CONST from "./constantsFile";

const initialState = {
...MY_CONST
}
export const AbcReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {.....}

ABC.jsx
------------
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
const ABC = () => {
const const1 = useSelector(state) => state. AbcReducer. MY_CONSTANT1:
const const2 = useSelector(state) => state. AbcReducer. MY_CONSTANT2:
.......
```

Now we can easily mock the store in test.jsx and provide the values to constant that we want.

```
Abc.text.jsx
-------------
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';

describe('Abc mock constants in jest', () => {
const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);
let store = mockStore({
   AbcReducer: {
      MY_CONSTANT1 ="MOCKTEST",
      MY_CONSTANT2 = "MOCKBEST",
   }
});

test('your test here', () => { .....
```

Now when the test runs it will always pick the constant value form mock store.

Answer (score -1):

In case you would like to mock a specific constant from a module and retain the values of other exports, you could use the requireActual method provided by jest and override specific value like this

```
jest.mock('./constants', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('./constants'),
  CONSTANT_TO_OVERRIDE: 3
}));
```

This is useful if your code imports multiple values from a module and you are only trying to override one of those values. With this approach you do not have to redefine all values that are consumed for your test to work fine.