# Jest mocked object only for one test

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ts-jest

I have mocked an object (in my case the quizData), but it should only mocked for one Test.
How can I achieve this?

My code looks like this so far:

```
import {fireEvent, render, screen} from '@testing-library/react';
import App from "./App.tsx";

jest.mock("./QuizData", () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    quizData: [{
        id: 1,
        question: 'What is the capital of France?',
        answers: ['Paris', 'London', 'Berlin', 'Madrid'],
        correctAnswer: 'Paris',
    },]
}));

describe('Test the App Component', () => {

    it('checkAnswer updates score and user answers correctly', () => {
        render(<App/>);
        const startButton = screen.getByRole('startButton');
        fireEvent.click(startButton);
        const answerButton = screen.getByText("Paris");
        fireEvent.click(answerButton);
        expect(screen.getByText("Score: 100")).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    // Test that don't work with mock ???
    it('Test the next button', () => {
        render(<App/>);
        const startButton = screen.getByRole('startButton');
        fireEvent.click(startButton);
        const nextButton = screen.getByRole('nextButton');
        fireEvent.click(nextButton);
        expect(screen.getByText("Question: 2 / 10")).toBeInTheDocument();
    })
});
```

I have already tried a lot with `unmock` and `mockReturnValue`. Unfortunately, none of this worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocking constants is a bit tricky, so why not make your code more testable (which is usually a noble goal anyway, that can improve code quality) by instead having `QuizData` export a function that returns the data.

```
export const getQuizData => ({  }) // Put your data in the return obkect
```

In your codebase, you will now need to call this method instead of assuming you already have the constant.

Then you can mock it using spies in your tests like so:

```
import * as quizData from "./QuizData"
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react"
import App from "./App.tsx"

describe("Test the App Component", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks()
  })

  // Mock is for this test only
  it("checkAnswer updates score and user answers correctly", () => {
    const mock = jest.spyon(quizData, "getQuizData")
    mock.mockReturnValue([
      {
        id: 1,
        question: "What is the capital of France?",
        answers: ["Paris", "London", "Berlin", "Madrid"],
        correctAnswer: "Paris",
      },
    ])
    render(<App />)
    const startButton = screen.getByRole("startButton")
    fireEvent.click(startButton)
    const answerButton = screen.getByText("Paris")
    fireEvent.click(answerButton)
    expect(screen.getByText("Score: 100")).toBeInTheDocument()
  })

  // Now uses original implementation since the mock was reset in afterEach
  it("Test the next button", () => {
    render(<App />)
    const startButton = screen.getByRole("startButton")
    fireEvent.click(startButton)
    const nextButton = screen.getByRole("nextButton")
    fireEvent.click(nextButton)
    expect(screen.getByText("Question: 2 / 10")).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

If you really don't want to change to a function [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64019066/1086398). However, I strongly recommend just making your code more testable like above.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can split your file in two different testing files, to have the mock in the file you want it , so something like:

**First file, with mock**

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from "./App.tsx";

jest.mock("./QuizData", () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    quizData: [{
        id: 1,
        question: 'What is the capital of France?',
        answers: ['Paris', 'London', 'Berlin', 'Madrid'],
        correctAnswer: 'Paris',
    },]
}));

describe('Test the App Component', () => {
    it('checkAnswer updates score and user answers correctly', () => {
        render(<App/>);
        const startButton = screen.getByRole('startButton');
        fireEvent.click(startButton);
        const answerButton = screen.getByText("Paris");
        fireEvent.click(answerButton);
        expect(screen.getByText("Score: 100")).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

**Second file, no mock**

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from "./App.tsx";

describe('Test the App Component', () => {
    it('Test the next button', () => {
        render(<App/>);
        const startButton = screen.getByRole('startButton');
        fireEvent.click(startButton);
        const nextButton = screen.getByRole('nextButton');
        fireEvent.click(nextButton);
        expect(screen.getByText("Question: 2 / 10")).toBeInTheDocument();
    })
});
```

Comment: Yes, it works, of course, but it's not very nice.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to define a generic mock and then define the single mock implementations with mockImplementation()

```
import {fireEvent, render, screen} from '@testing-library/react';
import App from "./App.tsx";

jest.mock("./QuizData");

import QuizData from './QuizData';

describe('Test the App Component', () => {

    it('checkAnswer updates score and user answers correctly', () => {
        mockQuiz.mockImplementation(() => ({
            __esModule: true,
            quizData: [{
               id: 1,
               question: 'What is the capital of France?',
               answers: ['Paris', 'London', 'Berlin', 'Madrid'],
               correctAnswer: 'Paris',
           },]
        })
        render(<App/>);
        const startButton = screen.getByRole('startButton');
        fireEvent.click(startButton);
        const answerButton = screen.getByText("Paris");
        fireEvent.click(answerButton);
        expect(screen.getByText("Score: 100")).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    //... other tests
});
```

Comment: The mock must be in front of the describe. And if it were that simple, I wouldn't ask.  I wish it were that simple

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question, I updated the answer accordingly