# Mock a constant property from a module for a specific test group

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I have `MyComponent.tsx` that uses `constants.ts` module in order to do something based on the `IS_IOS` constant:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { platform } from '../../constants';

const { IS_IOS } = platform;
interface Props {}

export const MyComponent = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Alpha Beta { String(IS_IOS) }</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I am trying to mock `constants.ts` differently in each test. I have tried all methods from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977961/how-to-mock-an-exported-const-in-jest) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137311/jest-mock-a-constant-property-from-a-module-for-a-specific-test), but still no results. The module is not mocked at all. Here are my test file, and component file:

`MyComponent.test.tsx`:

```
// @ts-nocheck
import React from 'react';
import { cleanup, render } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import { MyComponent } from '../../../src/MyComponent';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    cleanup();
  });

  it('one', () => {
    jest.mock('../../../src/constants', () => ({
      platform: { IS_IOS: false }
    }));

    const { debug } = render(<MyComponent/>);
    debug();
  });

  it('two', () => {
    jest.mock('../../../src/constants', () => ({
      platform: { IS_IOS: true }
    }));

    const { debug } = render(<MyComponent/>);
    debug();
  });
});
```

This is the result that I get into the console:

```
  console.log
    <View>
      <Text>
        Alpha Beta 
        true
      </Text>
    </View>

      at debugDeep (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/build/helpers/debugDeep.js:19:13)

  console.log
    <View>
      <Text>
        Alpha Beta 
        true
      </Text>
    </View>

      at debugDeep (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/build/helpers/debugDeep.js:19:13)
```

Now, it works if I put `jest.mock` at the beginning of the file, but the problem is that it mocks `IS_IOS` with same value (i.e. `IS_IOS = false`):

```
// @ts-nocheck
import React from 'react';
import { cleanup, render } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import { MyComponent } from '../../../src/MyComponent';

jest.mock('../../../src/constants', () => ({
  platform: { IS_IOS: false }
}));

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    cleanup();
  });

  it('one', () => {
    const { debug } = render(<MyComponent/>);
    debug();
  });

  it('two', () => {
    const { debug } = render(<MyComponent/>);
    debug();
  });
});
```

As I said, mocks in both cases:

```
  console.log
    <View>
      <Text>
        Alpha Beta 
        false
      </Text>
    </View>

      at debugDeep (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/build/helpers/debugDeep.js:19:13)

  console.log
    <View>
      <Text>
        Alpha Beta 
        false
      </Text>
    </View>

      at debugDeep (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/build/helpers/debugDeep.js:19:13)
```

I have tried [`jest.doMock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options), tried adding `__esModule` - none of it works. How do I mock module differently in each test?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jest.resetModules` cannot affect modules that have already been imported. It should be combined with `require` that is local to a test in order for test-specific `jest.mock` to affect it.

ES modules should be mocked with magic `__esModule` property in order for them to not be processed as CommonJS modules:

```
jest.mock('../../../src/constants', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  platform: { IS_IOS: false }
}));
const { MyComponent } = require('../../../src/MyComponent');
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but how do I use this knowledge to solve my problem? I can't move imports from MyComponent into my tests.

Comment: You shouldn't necessarily move them, although nothing prevents you from doing that. You should use them in addition to top-level imports. A test uses `MyComponent` that is local to it. The same applies to any other import that depends on test-specific mock.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was exactly what I needed! I also had to write it like that: `{ MyComponent: MyComponentLocal }` to comply with eslint no-shadow requirement.