Mock module exporting constant
I have the following foo and bar modules:
bar.mjs:
export const BAR = 'production'

foo.mjs:
import { BAR } from "./bar.mjs";

export const FOO = () => BAR

I want to test FOO mocking bar and having another value for the constant BAR.
I have read this question and the answer doesn't work (the solution relied on the constant being defined as var rather than const).
baz.test.js:
import { FOO } from "./foo.mjs";
import { jest } from '@jest/globals'

test('Mock test', () => {
    jest.mock('./bar.mjs', () => ({
        BAR: 'mocked'
    }))
    console.log(FOO())
})

I think this doesn't work because FOO's closure captures the value of BAR at the moment the foo module is imported.
What is the correct solution to mocking a constant?

"this question" - what question? Have you tried delaying the import of FOO until after the mock is in place?

@jonrsharpe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977961/how-to-mock-an-exported-const-in-jest missing link. I don't want to use the commonjs syntax require. I have seen the import keywork and have tried to no avail

You don't have to use require, the docs have ESM examples too: https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options. Tried what, to no avail? Give a [mre].
